# Unable to open Google Cloud DNS page

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I am unable to access Google Cloud DNS page.

All it shows is:
"DNS API is being enabled. This may take a minute or more."
Then it reloads and repeats showing the same message.

The API is already enabled, and the records I created works. No problem with DNS.
I need to modify records, but I can't because of this problem.

I tried opening the page in different computers and different browsers without addons, same result.

If there is a better place to ask, please do tell.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the page regardless of what computer / browser you're using.

If you cannot it's either a [temporary outage which you can check here](https://status.cloud.google.com/) or a bug.

The only thing to do here is to [contact paid support](https://cloud.google.com/support) for more immediate help and if the time is something you can afford [report this at Google's IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187241&template=1162897) and get help for free - however it may take a few days. It is possible that only you are affected. Please describe the issue in as much detail as possible - this will expidete the process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try disabling and enabling the API, if it didn't help then will contact paid support.

Comment: If my helped you in any way please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Sure...first time.